# открытые сабменю по клику

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть две части меню, по клику на которые должно открываться соответствующее сабменю. У меня открываются оба сабменю. Как сделать их независимыми друг от друга?

```js
<template>
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="accordion" v-for="work of works" :key="${work}${work}">
    <li @click="isActive = !isActive">
      <div class="accordion__title" >{{work.name}}</div> 
        <ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu', {'hidden' : !isActive}]">
      <li  class="submenu submenu__item" v-for="category in work.categories" :key="${category}${category}`">{{category}}
```

```js
export default { name: 'NavMenu', data: () => ({ isActive: true, works: [ {name: 'archetecture', categories: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']}, {name: 'not archetecture', categories: ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']} ] }), } `
```

Comment: По моему кода немного не хватает

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:
В каждый объект массива works добавить свойство show:false

```
works: [ 
  {
    name: 'archetecture',
    show: false,
    categories: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']
  }, 
  {
    name: 'not archetecture',
    show: false,
    categories: ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']
  } 
]
```

Цикл сделать не на `<ul>`, а на `<li>`. Так думаю будет логичнее

```
<li v-for="(work, index) of works" :key="index" @click="isActive(index)">
```

Ключ :key заменил на индекс, но это не принципиально, можете оставить свое значение. Событию `@click` передаем индекс элемента массива. И теперь остается только изменить в нужном элементе массива свойство `show`

```
methods: {
  isActive(index) {
    this.works.forEach(el => el.show = false);
    this.works[index].show = !this.works[index].show;
  }
}
```

И соответствующее подменю отображаем в зависимости от свойства `show`

```
<ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu']" v-if="work.show">
```

Теперь каждое подменю работает независимо

Comment: при Вашем подходе, если кликнуть на 1 меню, а потом на 2-е, то остануться оба открытыми. Проблему надо решать через переменную типа `activeIndex`.

Comment: Да. Условия о закрытии другого я нигде не видел. Это поправить особого труда не составит

Comment: да, нужен цикл - но зачем

Comment: Напишите свой способ. Я решил задачу таким образом

Comment: Не хочу быть занудой, но Вы ее не решили, по причине указанной в первом комментарии. И я то могу написать ответ, но  предлагю Вам исправить код, чтобы именно Ваш ответ был принят, а не мой.

Comment: Хорошо. Добавил цикл. Теперь Ваш внутренний зануда успокоен?))) Напишите какой метод предлагаете Вы. Мне лично интересно как решить это через activeIndex

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант (на основании `activeIndex` - индекс активного элемента(объекта) в вашем входном массиве). При нажатии добавляете индекс элемента, на котором нажали в `activeIndex` и далее используете его значение, чтобы распределить кому отображаться, а кому и "скрыться":

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    activeIndex: null,
    works: [{
      name: 'archetecture',
      categories: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']
    }, {
      name: 'not archetecture',
      categories: ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']
    }]
  }),
  methods: {
    openSubmenu(id) {
      this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex === id ? null : id
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li @click="openSubmenu(index)"  v-for="(work, index) of works" :key="index">
        <div class="accordion__title">{{work.name}}</div>
        <ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu', {'hidden' : index !== activeIndex}]">
          <li class="submenu submenu__item" v-for="category in work.categories" :key="category">{{category}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант, где вместо индекса используется уникальный идентификатор (`id`) каждого отдельного пункта меню(если он есть конечно):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    activeId: null,
    works: [{
      id: 'uid1',
      name: 'archetecture',
      categories: ['interior', 'exterior', 'vr', 'animation']
    }, {
      id: 'uid2',
      name: 'not archetecture',
      categories: ['commrcial', 'video', '3D art']
    }]
  }),
  methods: {
    openSubmenu(id) {
      this.activeId = this.activeId === id ? null : id
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li @click="openSubmenu(work.id)" v-for="(work, index) of works">
        <div class="accordion__title">{{work.name}}</div>
        <ul :class="['accordion__submenu submenu', {'hidden' : work.id !== activeId}]">
          <li class="submenu submenu__item" v-for="category in work.categories">{{category}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```